# How to call unique_ptr constructor with deleter?

Tags: c++

I try to initialize my `std::unique_ptr` but it fails to compile:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<int, void (*)(int*)>::unique_ptr(int*, void (&)(void*) throw ())’

m_head((int*)malloc(m_capacity * sizeof(int)), std::free) {
                                                        ^
```

This my code:

```
class deque {
    const int INC_ARRAY = 2;

    int m_front, m_back;
    int m_capacity;
    std::unique_ptr<int, void (*)(int *)> m_head;

public:
    const int EMPTY_DEQUE = -1;

    /**
     * @brief Constructor
     */
    deque()
        : m_front{INC_ARRAY - 1}, m_back{INC_ARRAY},
        m_capacity{2 * INC_ARRAY},
        m_head{(int*)malloc(m_capacity * sizeof(int)), std::free} {
    }
};
```

I need to use `malloc`, not `new`. How to initialize it correctly?

**P.S.** I'm learning C++ only

Comment: You might want to use a `static_cast<int *>(malloc ...)` instead of the C-style cast you're using. I think `static_cast` will work, but you may need `reinterpret_cast`. These casts are more specific (and therefor safer) than C style casts. They are also easier to pick out in the code.

Comment: @Omnifarious, thank you for advice!

Comment: "*I need to use `malloc`, not `new`*" - why? `malloc` is C, not C++. `new` is the official way to allocate memory in C++. For that matter, all you are doing is allocating a dynamic array that is freed automatically. C++ has a `std::vector` class for that very purpose.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - My guess is that the OP is in a class being taught by someone who hasn't bothered to learn anything about how to write in code in C++ since the mid-90s. Which makes it all the more interesting that the OP is using `unique_ptr`. Perhaps the OP is trying to squeeze in what modern C++ he or she can within the structure of the course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `std::free` is `void free(void*)`. It doesn't take `int*`. Change your deleter type.

```
std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(void*)> m_head;
```

Comment: A safer way to pass the correct signature is to use [`decltype()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) instead, eg: `std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(std::free)> m_head;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `decltype(&std::free)`, but otherwise, yeah.